# Why websockets clients are not added to map

Tags: go, websocket

I have websocket server developed in golang using gorilla websockets package and I'm using map to store the clients.

```
func serveWs(pool *Pool, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := Upgrade(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+v\n", err)
    }

    client := &Client{
        Id: uuid.New(),
        Conn: conn,
        Pool: pool,
        SubsTopics: make(map[string]string),
        UnsubChan: make(chan bool),
    }

    pool.Connect <- client

    client.ReadMessage()
}

func (pool *Pool) Start() {
    for {
        select {
        case client := <-pool.Connect:
            pool.Clients[client] = true
            fmt.Println("Size of Connection Pool: ", len(pool.Clients), " & " ,client.Id)
            break
        case client := <-pool.Disconnect:
            client.UnsubChan <- true
            delete(pool.Clients, client)
            fmt.Println("Size of Connection Pool: ", len(pool.Clients), " & " ,client.Id)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm adding and removing clients. By these logs imm get to know number of clients connected.

I did load testing of that server using k6 package. While testing for 10000 clients if the connections reachs 5000 clients it is not increasing more than that it was staying in 5000 itself and at the end of the test it disconnects those clients without any error.

What might be the reason behind these issue and how to fix this?

Note: even if I reduce the clients count in load testing tool as 1000, even though after 300 - 400 clients the connections count stays between 300-350 and at the end it was disconnecting every clients without any error.

Comment: Is the operating system configured to allow 10000 open file descriptors in a process? Determine whether the client is establishing connections by checking the following: Is `serveWs` called the expected number of time?  Does `Upgrade` return successfully on each call?

Comment: I dont know about file descriptors.
I tried that totally serveWS method called 40000 thousand times and the length of the client map at max is 8100 and the program ended without error

Comment: Also, this is the memory stats at the end
--------------------------------------
Memory Statistics Reporting time:  2023-05-17 18:19:55.076359868 +0530 IST m=+80.995052358
--------------------------------------
Bytes of allocated heap objects:  4399384008
Total bytes of Heap object:  8345136648
Bytes of memory obtained from OS:  4878848744
Count of heap objects:  28893568
Count of heap objects freed:  17307711
Count of live heap objects 11585857
Number of completed GC cycles:  14
--------------------------------------